# Chrome not running my D3.js, but it is working fine in safari

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm kind of new to D3.js. Chrome is not running my D3.js, but it is working fine in safari.
What is wrong with my code here? Pls assist

Is this due to some permissions issue where Chrome disallows XMLHttpRequest (d3.json etc.) when running files from server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}

</style>
<body>
Show: <select id="graph">
  <option value="init">Before topic identification</option>
  <option value="final">After topic identification</option>
</select>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 1000;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .friction(0.99)
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(100)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("cluster.json", function(error, graph) {
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", 0);

  var gnodes = svg.selectAll("g.gnode")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter()
      .append('g')
      .classed('gnode', true);

  // Add one circle in each group
  var node = gnodes.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.initValue*2; })
    .style("fill", color(0))
    .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return (d.type=="term") ? 0 : 0.75; })
    .call(force.drag);

  // Append the labels to each group
  var labels = gnodes.append("text")
      .style("opacity", function(d) {return d.initValue*2; })
      .attr("dy", ".3em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-size", function(d) {return 24+"px"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
        d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style('font-size', function(d) { return 45 })
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .style('fill', "red");
        d3.select(this).moveToFront();      
        })
    .on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
        d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style('font-size', function(d) { return 24 })
        .style("opacity", function(d) {return d.initValue*2; })
        .style('fill', "black");
    });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    // Translate the groups
    gnodes.attr("transform", function(d) { 
      return 'translate(' + [d.x, d.y] + ')'; 
    });    
  });

  d3.select("#graph").on("change", function() {    
    // Compute index per node.
    var thisValue = this.value;
    node.attr("r", function(d) { return (thisValue=="init") ? d.initValue*2 : ((d.type=="term") ? 50 : d.finalValue*2); });
    node.style("fill", function(d) { return (thisValue=="init") ? color(0) : color(d.group); });
    link.style("stroke-width", function(d) { return (thisValue=="init") ? 0 : 1; });
    force.linkDistance( function(d) { return ((thisValue=="init") ? d.initValue : d.finalValue*20); });
    force.start();
  });
});


</script>
```

**[cluster.json](http://dropbox.com/s/s2xqd6ftaxvajjz/cluster.json)**

Comment: You should check if there is an error message in the console and if there is one the show it with your question.

Comment: Please provide clickable example via jsfidle.net

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s2xqd6ftaxvajjz/cluster.json

Comment: please refer to json file.. html file codes already include in the question

Comment: Is there a error message in the console or is there no error message in the console? And please add detail (like the json or the error message)  to the question and not as comment.

Comment: note error.. page is not showing in chrome.. it is working fine in safari

Comment: You don't need to repeat something that you already wrote in your question (`page is not showing in chrome.. it is working fine in safari`). Anyway [jsfiddle.net/YSg36](http://jsfiddle.net/YSg36/) runs perfectly fine (I just set `graph` directly to test). So either your callback gets an error instead of graph or something else is wrong. But no matter what it is, if it works in Safari and not in Chrome and that is all you code then there **IS** an error message in the console, that tells you what is wrong. Or did you disable js in Chrome?

Comment: Javascript is already enabled in chrome

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you cannot load local files in Chrome with d3.json. But you can use jquery.get, something like this:

```
$.get( "cluster.json", function( data ) {
```

//     your code here
    });

PS: better use $.Deferred, resolve in your code.

But I guess, you use wrong cluster.json. Can you provide it?

Comment: Can you provide your cluster.json?

Comment: Not being able to load local files is a security restriction. If this is the reason, then `jQuery.get` also should not work, as both use `XMLHttpRequest` internally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your code on some local server.. like

```
  localhost:8080
```

If you have Wamp or any php server installed than just copy past your code in www root folder and run it from phpMyAdmin

if you have python installed open command promp , go to that directory and type this command for

```
   python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

and you will be able to run your local server on that directory